# Area under a histogram

Tags: histogram, density-estimation

Perhaps a basic question, if I have an un-normalised histogram, my understanding was that the integral is simply the total number of points.

If I then fit a curve over the the histogram, then surely if I integrate this curve from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ I should get a value that is very close to the total number of points in my histogram's data set -- correct?

If the histogram and the curve is centred around $0$ are there any special considerations, for example normalising?